# Determining the speed of convergence of a sequence, using the relative error equation.

Tags: general-topology

The problem I'm finding trouble with is this.
$$x_{n+1}:={1\over 2}(x_n+{a\over x_n}) \ (a\in R, a>0, n\in N\cup{\{0\}}, and \ x_0\gt 0 \ arbitrary)$$
Show that $x_n$ converges and determine the limit x. Consider the relative error $e_n:={x_n-x\over x}$. What can you say about the speed of convergence?

Now I've already proven that $x_n$ converges, and that the limit x should be $\sqrt{a}$. However, I can't even get a clue about the last question regarding the speed of convergence and the relative error equation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try to express $e_{n+1}$ in terms of $e_n$.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I came up with $e_{n+1}=(e_n)^2/{2e_n+1}$. So I think I can prove $e_{n+1}<e_n$, inductively. Then is it enough to say that the speed of convergence gets faster as n increases?

Comment: This is $e_{n+1}=e_n/2+1$, which actually shows non-convergence (as ther error tends to one). You should obtain a much better result, double check.